# Pass inline php code into jade mixin argument

Tags: php, html, pug

I'm recently trying to write PHP and jade together and facing to this problem. Is there a way to pass Inline PHP code into Jade's Mixin as an argument? Something like this

```
mixin articleTitle(title)
 h2= title

#blogSection
 +articleTitle('<?php echo 'asd';?>')
```

My expectation result

```
<div id="blogSection">
 <h2>asd</h>
</div>
```

Of course, I can expand that Mixin and pass PHP inline code directly into it but I want to know if there's another way to do that through Mixin argument. Thank you very much for reading this and sorry for my English.

Comment: Are you using jade-php npm package?

Comment: no, I use an original jade parser in CodeKit